# how to get data of a specific user from a django model and store each field in a separate variable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model named Credit with 16 fields. I want to fetch data of a specific user using primary key and store value of each field in the separate variable because i have to perform some mathematical operation on these data. These data are required to be passed to a python script. How can i get this done?

Comment: You need to try with some effort and ask you have specific issue, look at [guide to ask in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a model to dictionary and use unpack to pass it to a function or assign to variable.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk={pk})
d = user.__dict__
some_function(**d)
```

now in some function you can write the variable you want

```
def some_function(username, is_superuser, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
    pass
```